# Why is my custom filter in Meteor reactive-table is not working?

Tags: javascript, meteor, filtering, html-table

I am trying to make a custom filter for my [reactive-table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table) but it doesn't seems to work.

This is my code:

```
Template.selectPartnerFilter.created = function () {
  this.filter = new ReactiveTable.Filter('partner-filter', ['partner_id']);
};

Template.selectPartnerFilter.events({
   "change #raw-data-filter" : function (event, template) {
      var input = $(event.target).val();
      if (!_.isNaN(input)) {
        template.filter.set(input);
      } else {
        template.filter.set("");
      }
   }
});
```

with the following template code:

```
<template name="selectPartnerFilter">
   <select name="" id="raw-data-filter">
        <option value="">Filter by partner</option>
        {{#each partners}}
            <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

What else should I do, in order to make it work in my table?

```
<div class="panel-body">
  {{> selectPartnerFilter}}
  {{> reactiveTable settings=settings}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify which part is not working? Where does the outcome differ from what you expected?

Comment: try `Template.selectPartnerFilter.onCreated`.

Comment: The filter responses on "change" event and i get the value selected.  template.filter.set(input); also works since i logged filter.get() after it and its good. But nothing happens on table data. Table data doesn't change anyway.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `settings` helper?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are setting your filter in the settings as:

```
settings = {
    // And some other settings you have already set and so on.
    filters: [
        'partner-filter'
    ]
}
```

Instead of adding the instance, you have to write the unique identifier of the filter in order for filtering to work.